# how can I center my text on fpdf

Tags: php, fpdf

I have finding on internet about how to center the text on fpdf or one way to center my text but I didnt find it. by the way it's just the title I need to center

```
<?php  
        require('../fpdf/fpdf.php');
        class Ticket extends FPDF{
            private $conexion;
            public function __construct(){
                require_once('../model/conexion.php');
                parent::__construct();
                $this->conexion = new conexion();
                $this->conexion->conectar();
            }
        }

        $pdf = new FPDF('P','mm',array(114,76)); 
        $pdf->AddPage(); 
        $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);
        $pdf->Cell(0,0,'StoreLTE');
        $pdf->Ln(2);
        $pdf->Output('test.pdf', 'i'); 
    ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `Cell` method includes optional var for alignment 
http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/cell.htm

You can include the additional options variables and define the alignment as center.

```
$pdf->Cell(0,0,'StoreLTE',0,1,'C');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$pdf->MultiCell(0,0, $user_name , $border=0, $align='C', $fill=false);
```

Just give `$align='C'`. This works for me.